# similar substring in other string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, substring, strpos

How to check substrings in PHP by prefix or postfix.
For example, I have the search string named as `$to_search` as follows:

```
$to_search = "abcdef"
```

And three cases to check the if that is the substring in $to_search as follows:

```
$cases = ["abc def", "def", "deff", ... Other values ...];
```

Now I have to detect the first three cases using `substr()` function.
How can I detect the `"abc def", "def", "deff"` as substring of `"abcdef"` in PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to find out which elements of $cases array are substrings of $to_search?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I want to search first three as sub string of the $to_search

Comment: First three elements in $cases that are substrings of $to_search, correct?

Comment: How is `deff` a substring of `abcdef`?

Comment: its not exact substring but I want as because def is postfix of abcdef

Comment: You would have to start by explicitly defining logic for matching because this is currently missing. Your *'deff' contains 'def' which is in 'abcdef'* is very... uhmm... **fuzzy**.

Comment: So you want to find any strings that either begin or end with either the beginning or ending of the search string?

Comment: yeah. exactly. that what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find any of the cases that either begin with or end with either the beginning or ending of the search string, I don't know of another way to do it than to just step through all of the possible beginning and ending combinations and check them. There's probably a better way to do this, but this should do it.

```
$to_search = "abcdef";
$cases = ["abc def", "def", "deff", "otherabc", "noabcmatch", "nodefmatch"];

$matches = array();
$len = strlen($to_search);
for ($i=1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
    // get the beginning and end of the search string of length $i
    $pre_post = array();
    $pre_post[] = substr($to_search, 0, $i);
    $pre_post[] = substr($to_search, -$i);

    foreach ($cases as $case) {
        // get the beginning and end of each case of length $i
        $pre = substr($case, 0, $i);
        $post = substr($case, -$i);

        // check if any of them match
        if (in_array($pre, $pre_post) || in_array($post, $pre_post)) {
            // using the case as the array key for $matches will keep it distinct
            $matches[$case] = true;
        }
    }
}
// use array_keys() to get the keys back to values
var_dump(array_keys($matches));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [Levenshtein distance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) between the two words useful - it'll have a value of `1` for `abc def`. However your problem is not well defined - matching strings that are "similar" doesn't mean anything concrete.

Edit - If you set the deletion cost to 0 then this very closely models the problem you are proposing. Just check that the levenshtein distance is less than 1 for everything in the array.

Comment: @developer I think this is what you want. A measure of text similarity rather than substrings. Substrings are exact. This a a heuristic similarity comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This will find if any of the strings inside $cases are a substring of $to_search.

```
foreach($cases as $someString){
    if(strpos($to_search, $someString) !== false){
        // $someString is found inside $to_search
    }
}
```

Only "def" is though as none of the other strings have much to do with each other.

Also on a side not; it is prefix and suffix not postfix.

Comment: yes, but I want to detect the rest of cases as well. only "def" I tried earlier but I want the rest of the cases as well as sub string.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know what you mean. This loop will find any word that is a substring of the search term. The examples that you have given are not substrings of the search term you gave.

Comment: yes, you are right, they aren't substrings but they had substrings in the form of postfix or prefix or similar words. I want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function like this:

```
$cases = ["cake", "cakes", "flowers", "chocolate", "chocolates"];
$to_search = "chocolatecake";
$search = strtolower($to_search);

$arr = array_filter($cases, function($val) use ($search) { return
  strpos( $search,
      str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('/s$/', '', strtolower($val))) ) !== FALSE; });

print_r($arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cake
    [1] => cakes
    [3] => chocolate
    [4] => chocolates
)
```

As you can it prints all the values you expected apart from `deff` which is not part of search string `abcdef` as I commented above.

Comment: Your are almost right, but how to detect the part of abcdef as def ?

Comment: is there any possible that also prints deff? just putting last word as aspumtion ?

Comment: in `deff` and `abcdef` we have a common `def`

Comment: That's not good enough logic for code, then it should find `destiny` also because `de` is common.

Comment: I want to find the words with "s" and without "s" actually as a real example of english words.

Comment: Hmm let me give it. I had words, cake, cakes, cholcolatecake etc. and my serach term is cholcolate cake.